# How to pass a newly defined variable from js.erb to html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I've got a controller method that passes either an integer variable or an array of integers variable.  I have to look through in my `.js.erb` file to reassign `td`s with the appropriate integer.  How do I take the value of the current object of the array and pass it to html.erb to render?

Here's the .js.erb file:

```
<% if @pos_range %>
    <% @pos_range.each do |p|%>
        $("td#add_bar_<%= p %>").replaceWith("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'foos/update_bar_position', :locals => { :id => @foo.id, :position_str => @position_str } ))%>");
        $("td#add_bar_button_<%= p %>").replaceWith("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'foos/update_bar_position_button', :locals => { :id => @foo.id, :position_str => @position_str } ))%>");
    <% end %>
<% else %>
    $("td#add_bar_<%= @position %>").replaceWith("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'foos/update_bar_position', :locals => { :id => @foo.id, :position_str => @position_str } ))%>");
    $("td#add_bar_button_<%= @position %>").replaceWith("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'foos/update_bar_position_button', :locals => { :id => @foo.id, :position_str => @position_str } ))%>");
<% end %>
```

Here is update_bar_position.  If the loop is used, the `p` results in the new `td`s being named 'remove_name_':

```
<% if @position %>
    <td id=<%="remove_name_#{@position.to_s}"%>>
        <%= @position_str %>&nbsp;
    </td>
<% else %>
    <td id=<%="remove_name_#{p.to_s}"%>>
        <%= @position_str %>&nbsp;
    </td>
<% end %>
```

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use each_with_index

```
<% if @pos_range %>
<% @pos_range.each_with_index do |p, i|%>
    $("td#add_bar_<%= p %>").replaceWith("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'foos/update_bar_position', :locals => { :id => @foo.id, :position_str => @position_str, :index => i } ))%>");
    $("td#add_bar_button_<%= p %>").replaceWith("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'foos/update_bar_position_button', :locals => { :id => @foo.id, :position_str => @position_str } ))%>");
<% end %>
```

In your .html.erb file you can access the variable 'index'

Comment: I'm thinking this leaves me with my original problem.  Even if I try to call `i` haere in html.erb, it won't know what I'm talking about.  It seems .html.erb files can only print variables from the controller.  Also I do not need the value of the index.  Perhaps I didn't phrase my question clearly.  Thanks.

Comment: why would you need to call i from the html.erb file? To pass variables into view files you should use :locals 
I suppose I don't understand what you're trying to do. If you are trying to pass different items based on their type, perhaps try applying is_a?Array and then applying the different conditions based on the result of that.